# The contradiction on the return values of PostMessageA and WM_MOUSEMOVE

Tags: c++, windows

I want to post WM_MOUSEMOVE message using Windows api `PostMessageA`. In the microsoft document on [WM_MOUSEMOVE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-input), it says:

> If an application processes this message, it should return zero.

And in the one on [`PostMessageA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea), it says:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero. If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError. GetLastError returns ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA when the limit is hit.

Aren't they contradictory? In my program, I wrote these codes:

```cpp
// ...
// mainGameWnd is the handle on the main window
// wParamRawMouse = 0, which indicates no mouse button was pressed
// _mouse_position.x and _mouse_position.y are LONG type
if ((PostMessageA(mainGameWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, wParamRawMouse, MAKELPARAM(_mouse_position.x, _mouse_position.y))) == 0);
{
    // error logging
    LogError("post message in Mouse move failed. Error: %ld", GetLastError());
}
```

In the log file, I found this line:

```
[Error]:  post message in Mouse move failed. Error: 0
```

What exactly the meaning of the returned "0" ? Did it mean `PostMessageA` failed and I should check the parameters sent into it or just the message was processed successfully and I needed do nothing?

#### Appendix

About the LogError

```cpp
// global: FILE* logFile = stdout;
// lastLog is enum
void Log(LogCategory level, LPCSTR format, bool append, va_list args)
{
    lastLog = level;
    if (!(LogFlag & (1 << level)))
        return;
    if (logEventFunc)
    {
        if (!logEventFunc(level, format, append, args))
            return;
    }
    if (!append)
    {
        time_t rawtime;
        char pblgtime[128] = { 0 };
        time(&rawtime);
        switch (level)
        {
        case Log_Error: strftime(pblgtime, 128, "%Y-%m-%d %X [Error]:  ", localtime(&rawtime)); break;
        }
        fprintf(logFile, pblgtime);
    }
    vfprintf(logFile, format, args);
    fflush(logFile);
}

void LogError(LPCSTR format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    Log(Log_Error, format, false, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: The value returned by `PostMessage` is not the same thing as the value that your application returns from its window procedure. There is no contradiction.

Comment: What does `LogError` expand to?

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks for commenting. So does the result of the example above indicate postmessage failed? And LogError just writes the formated string in a file.

Comment: It indicates that 1) something failed, and 2) your `LogError` macro does something before `GetLastError` is called. (I didn't ask what `LogError` does, I asked what it expands to; its definition.)

Comment: @molbdnilo I have added it in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the log file, I found this line:
>
> `[Error]:  post message in Mouse move failed. Error: 0`
>
> What exactly the meaning of the returned "0" ?

Nothing. You have an erroneous `;` on the end of your `if` statement, so it doesn't matter what value `PostMessageA()` returns, because `LogError()` will be called **unconditionally** and be passed an *indeterminate* `GetLastError()` value, which just *happened* to be 0.

You need to get rid of that `;`:

```cpp
if (PostMessageA(mainGameWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, wParamRawMouse, MAKELPARAM(_mouse_position.x, _mouse_position.y)) == 0)
{
    // error logging
    LogError("post message in Mouse move failed. Error: %ld", GetLastError());
}
```

Now, with that said:

> Did it mean PostMessageA failed and I should check the parameters sent into it or just the message was processed successfully and I needed do nothing?

With *proper* error checking in place, a return value of 0 means that `PostMessageA()` itself failed. The message's return value is NOT returned to you. Only the `SendMessage....()` functions can do that.

Comment: Thanks! How stupid I am! By the way, how to get the return value of a specifc message?  Use `sendmessage` instead?

Comment: @DerekLu yes, you would have to use `SendMessage()` instead. But not all messages are meant to be sent, and not all posted messages are processed in a window procedure, so sending a message that is meant to be posted may not get you the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

PostMessage is asynchronous.  It can only enqueue a message to the thread of the HWND. A successful return value form PostMessage indicates that the message was queued, not serviced or handled. So there's no return value from the handler to give back to the caller.

PostMessage can really only fail when:

- The hwnd is invalid
- There is no message queue associated with the given thread where the message is intended for (which is nearly impossible if you have an HWND)
- The queue is full

[SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) is synchronous and will return the result of the message handler for the given hwnd/msg pair. It invokes the wndproc message handler directly (or waits between threads for it to return) and delivers the return value back to the caller.

I'm not sure what you are really trying to do, but consider this:

1. Do you really need the return value from either PostMessage, SendMessage, or the associated handler?
2. Posting a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is a weird thing to do.  It doesn't actually move the mouse cursor. It just notifies the app that the mouse cursor moved (if it's interested in listening for that event).  At the actual system level, many mouse messages are neither posted nor sent. They are generated on the fly as a result of the thread invoking `GetMessage` and observing the mouse position state has changed since the last call.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 1. I just wanted to check whether PostMessage succeeded. 2. In my project, I hook some mouse-related Windows apis, and try to send mouse and keyboard message to a game process.

Comment: So Can I say there is no point to check the return value of postmessage?

Comment: Only you can decide if checking the return value of PostMessage is useful.

Comment: It's rare when PostMessage fails, but it can happen.  So you have to decide if it's something you want to do specifically if it fails.

Comment: In the example in my post above, the postmessage returned 0. Can I confirm that postmessage failed?

Comment: @DerekLu pretty much the only way `PostMessage()` fails is if the HWND is invalid, or its message queue is full. But that is not the case here, you have a typo in your code that is causing a fake result. See the answer I posted.